# open a splash view while loading data for my main view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a view in which I am fetchind data from the web - calling a php script and get a JSON response. The way that I do it is by performing an NSUrlRequest.

The way I do it is like this:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
..... 
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                             [NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
    [self.responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError");
    NSLog(@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[self.responseData length]);
...
}
```

Now I have another UIView, that wants to be displayed when that screen opens - like a splash screen only for this screen (which is not the starting screen) - it would be a how to use it screen. I want to be visible only for 5 secs for example.

If I place the `[self openCustomView]` inside the ViewDidLoad then I get a warning:

```
is not in the root view hierarchy
```

and the view does not open.

If I put in the `connectionDidFinishLoading` then I am waiting for the data to download which can take time.

Is there a way to preview that splash screen and download the data in the background?

My openCustomView is this:

```
 UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    CustomView *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomViewID"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of guessing but, from the message, I suspect you're calling `openCustomView` from the wrong spot.  I don't believe `self` (and its views) are considered part of the hierarchy during loading.  I'd try `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: +1 yip, they aren't there unless they actually appear